# can we able to recover the workspace oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have created one application in oracle application online, and i have not worked for 3months in it but i have worked before a lot and not even have a backup file of that application.

i got an email that "Your workspace is about to be purged!" and when i trying to login its saying "Workspace aaa will not be purged. Thank you."

But i cannot see the workspace again, please anyone help to recover the workspace in oracle application express

Comment: might get a better response at dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

This is a routine email that apex.oracle.com sends to purge workspaces - to remove dormant workspaces.

> Workspace will not be purged

this means that your workspace is still there.

you can go to apex.oracle.com and log in using your credentials

[image: apex login]

Comment: yes, i tried but it says that invalid login credentials, i cannot login the same workspace

Comment: Did you try clicking on the reset password? There is another option on the reset page called find my workspace if you are not sure about your workspace name.